# Unable to connect with clients present on a same network with two routers

Tags: networking, router

I have two routers R1 and R2 on a same subnet and connected LAN-LAN with the following config:

- R1 is a Dlink wireless router (DSL2750U) connected to internet via its WAN port.
- R2 is an old Huawei wireless router (hg520b)
- R1 config: static 192.168.1.1/24  **DHCP server enabled** and used as an **access point 1**
- R2 config: static 192.168.1.2/24  **DHCP server disabled** and used as an **access point 2**
- DHCP server @ pool: from .3 to .50

R1 and R2 Clients can access internet but I'm facing the following issues:

- R2 Clients cannot ping R1 clients and vice versa (streaming video for example)
- R2 Clients cannot detect a shared printer present on R1 although they are on the same subnet
- R1 Clients cannot connect to R2 admin page

Your help will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Since much is in place, then (a) are the WIreless NICs set to Private (NOT Public) and (b) have you got Network Discovery and File/Print sharing ON on both computers (Advanced Network Sharing)

Comment: Yes, in addition, everything work fine in case R1 clients try to detect a shared printer connectd to R1, same happen with R2 clients if the printer is connected to R2

Comment: The problem is when connexion  pass by R2

Comment: Give the printer a static IP on your network because setting it up DHCP can cause it to get lost

Comment: I did that too, i assigned to it ip adress 192.168.1.200

Comment: On one machine, open cmd.exe and type NET USE  Z: \\ipaddressofothercomputer\foldername .. What numerical error to you get.   Do the same the other way.  What if any error (numerical system error)

Comment: I substitute Z and foldername with what ?

Comment: Use a folder name from the other computer.  On the other computer, make a folder c:\temp and map to that. Do you get an error?

Comment: I got error 67. Just to remind you that clients connected see each other (got positif ping) only if they are connected to the same access point.

Comment: See:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/843156/you-receive-a-system-error-67-has-occurred-the-network-name-cannot-be

"This issue occurs if one of the following conditions is true:  The network components ...  are not configured correctly..  You may need to update the wireless driver or even the router firmware.